# C# Repeater focusing the first element after DataSource is changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Repeater with a certain DataSource (consisting of a list of images). The Repeater holds ImageButtons.

The aspx:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panSearch" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" BorderColor="#333333" BorderStyle="Inset" Width="500" Height="200">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate> 
            <asp:ImageButton OnClick="imgSearchResult_Click" BackColor="#333333" ID="imgSearchResult" height="32" width="32" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>'/> 
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Panel>
```

Additionally, I have a TextBox, which has a TextChanged-event in code-behind. I do a few things in there and at the end, my Repeater's DataSource will be overwritten with a new List of images (those images are put into the ImageButtons).

```
Repeater.DataSource = ImageList;
Repeater.DataBind();
```

**My problem:** Whenever my Repeater.DataSource is changed, it "clicks" the first ImageButton inside the Repeater. How do I prevent that from happening?

---

Full code:

My TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textSearch" runat="server" Width="80" OnTextChanged="textSearch_TextChanged" ForeColor="Black" />
```

My TextChanged event:

```
protected void textSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] filesindirectory = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images/ORAS"));
    List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image> ImageList = new List<System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image>(filesindirectory.Count());

    foreach (string item in filesindirectory)
    {
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image myImage= new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
        myImage.ImageUrl = (String.Format("~/Images/ORAS/{0}", System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item)));
        ImageList.Add(myImage);
    }
    Repeater.DataSource = ImageList;
    Repeater.DataBind();
}
```

When I click on an ImageButton inside the Repeater (which is executed when the text in my TextBox is changed):

```
protected void imgSearchResult_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedImage = sender as ImageButton;
    if (img1.ImageUrl == "~/Images/ORAS/Empty/000.png")
    {
        img1.ImageUrl = selectedImage.ImageUrl;
    }
    else if (img2.ImageUrl == "~/Images/ORAS/Empty/000.png")
    {
        img2.ImageUrl = selectedImage.ImageUrl;
    }
    else if (img3.ImageUrl == "~/Images/ORAS/Empty/000.png")
    {
        img3.ImageUrl = selectedImage.ImageUrl;
    }
    else if (img4.ImageUrl == "~/Images/ORAS/Empty/000.png")
    {
        img4.ImageUrl = selectedImage.ImageUrl;
    }
    else if (img5.ImageUrl == "~/Images/ORAS/Empty/000.png")
    {
        img5.ImageUrl = selectedImage.ImageUrl;
    }
    else if (img6.ImageUrl == "~/Images/ORAS/Empty/000.png")
    {
        img6.ImageUrl = selectedImage.ImageUrl;
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorMessage("Please remove one Image first!", true);
    }
}
```

Pageload:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        img1.ImageUrl = "~/Images/ORAS/Empty/000.png";
        img2.ImageUrl = "~/Images/ORAS/Empty/000.png";
        img3.ImageUrl = "~/Images/ORAS/Empty/000.png";
        img4.ImageUrl = "~/Images/ORAS/Empty/000.png";
        img5.ImageUrl = "~/Images/ORAS/Empty/000.png";
        img6.ImageUrl = "~/Images/ORAS/Empty/000.png";
        LoadImages();
    }
}
```

(LoadImages is almost 1:1 what's in my TextChanged function)

Comment: Show us a full code and full scenario..its difficult to understand the scenario.

Comment: @Justcode Okay, just a sec

Comment: A repeater is a "dumb" control. You'll need to tell it what to do. So basically you likely have to implement logic in the itemdatabound event.

Comment: Is the `TextChanged` event what causes the repeater to rebind?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen Hm.. I see.

Comment: @ShaiCohen Yes it is.

Comment: Can you please provide the `Page_Load` code?

Comment: @ShaiCohen I updated my question with the Page_Load at the bottom

Comment: I apologize. I am at a loss as to what the problem is.

Comment: @ShaiCohen After my textChanged event, the first ImageButton inside the Repeater receives the focus, ultimatively clicking it, causing my imgSearchResult_Click to fire. I also can't find a reason why that should happen.

Comment: 1. Are you sure your TextChanged event is firing when expected? I know this is not the issue you report however I would have thought you would need to set autoPostBack to true for this to work. 2. What do you mean precisely when you say that it "clicks" the first imageButton? Do you observe a second postback immediately after the first postback caused by the text change? Have you confirmed that this second postback causes the image click event to be fired with the first imagebutton being passed as the "sender" argument?

Comment: @rdans 1. Yes, whenever I change any text, it is firing. If I don't change the text, but still press enter (which does not fire the textChanged Event), the imageButton is clicked nonetheless. I think setting autoPostBack to true will break many things. 2. The imageButton lights up when you click it. It does so too after leaving the TextBox with Enter. The imageButton is passed as the Sender.

Comment: Do you have a `DefaultButton` property set anywhere in your code?

Comment: @Kohnarik...This question is unclear to me. When you say *`LoadImages` is almost 1:1 what's in my `TextChanged` function* so what is `TextChanged` usage? I just reproduced this and worked for me without any problem but I guess I've missed something when reproducing. Please clarify it more.

Comment: @user2946329 Well, I thought that it is irrelevant to mentiono, but LoadImages has a slight alteration of what TextChanged does. The only thing I could think of would be my jQuery, which clears my textBox everytime you click into it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really am not sure how (why) ASP.NET WebForms does it, but if you hit Enter and the form posts back, it will find the first control that implements `IPostBackEventHandler` and execute whatever event is bound to that. `ImageButton` implements it and so that's why it keeps firing the click event even though you didn't click on it. And, once again, only if you hit Enter.

I think that behaviour happens because the data posted back - `__EVENTTARGET` and `__EVENTARGUMENT` - are empty. Then ASP.NET goes bonkers.

You can solve it by putting a dummy button at the top of the page (or masterpage) and hide it using the style attribute. so:

```
<asp:Button ID="dummy" runat="server" style="display:none" />
```

Then in the init or load of your page (or masterpage) put

```
Form.DefaultButton = dummy.UniqueID;
```

That will force the button to capture the enter press instead of the arbitrary image button.

Comment: That solved my problem. If it's stupid, but it works, it isn't stupid. Thank you :)